# Scala compiler does not infer type properly

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

I am reading Chapter 6 of **Functional Programming in Scala**. I've approached the last exercise of the Chapter (i.e.: 6.11) and it makes
me doubtful about some line of codes.

Here it is the description of the exercise:

> Let's implement a finite state automaton that models a simple candy
>   dispenser. The machine has two inputs: you can insert a coin, or you
>   can dispense candy by turning the knob. It can be in one of two
>   states: locked or unlocked. It also tracks how many candies are left
>   and how many coins it contains.
>
> - Inserting a coin into a locked machine will unlock it if there’s still any candy left.
> - Turning the knob on an unlocked machine will cause it to dispense one candy and return to a locked state.
> - Turning the knob on a locked machine or inserting a coin into an unlocked machine has no effect.
> - A machine that’s out of candy ignores any kind of input.
>
> The method `simulateMachine` should operate the machine based on a
>   list of inputs and return the number of coins and candies left in the
>   machine. For instance, if the input Machine has 10 coins and 5
>   candies, and a total of 4 candies are bought successfully, the output
>   should be (14, 1).

The following is a testable unit of my own implementation.

```
object Test extends App {

  class Comparison(value: Int) {
    def shouldBe(other: Int): Boolean = value == other
  }

  implicit def enrichIntegers(value: Int) = new Comparison(value)

  val machine = Machine(locked  = true, candies = 5, coins = 10)
  val input = List(Coin, Turn, Coin, Turn, Coin, Turn, Coin, Turn)
  val result = StateChange.simulateMachine(input)
  val tuple: ((Int, Int), Machine) = result.run(machine)
  val ((coins, candies), _) = tuple

  (coins shouldBe 14) && (candies shouldBe 1) match {
    case true => println("Ok")
    case false => println("Ko")
  }
}

sealed trait Input
case object Coin extends Input
case object Turn extends Input
case class Machine(locked: Boolean, candies: Int, coins: Int)

case class State[S,+A](run: S => (A, S)) {
  def map[B](f: A => B): State[S, B] = State(
    s => {
      val (a, newState) = this.run(s)
      (f(a), newState)
    }
  )
  def map2[B,C](sb: State[S, B])(f: (A, B) => C): State[S, C] = State(
    s => {
      val (a, newState) = this.run(s)
      val (b, finalState) = sb.run(newState)
      (f(a, b), finalState)
    }
  )

  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = State(
    s => {
      val (a, state): (A, S) = this.run(s)
      f(a).run(state)
    }
  )
}

object State {

  def get[S]: State[S, S] = State(s => (s, s))
  def set[S](s: S): State[S, Unit] = State(_ => ((), s))

  def modify[S](f: S => S): State[S, Unit] = {
    for {
      s <- get
      _ <- set(f(s))
    } yield ()
  }

  def unit[S, A](a: A): State[S, A] = State(s => (a,s))

  def sequence[S, A](fs: List[State[S,A]]): State[S, List[A]] = {
    fs.foldRight[State[S, List[A]]](State.unit(Nil))((elem, acc) => elem.map2(acc)((a,b)=>a::b))
  }
}

object StateChange {
  def update(i: Input)(s: Machine) = {
    (i,s) match {
      case (_, Machine(_,0,_)) => s
      case (Coin, Machine(false,_,_)) => s
      case (Turn, Machine(true,_,_)) => s
      case (Coin, Machine(true,candies,coins)) => Machine(false,candies,coins+1)
      case (Turn, Machine(false,candies,coins)) => Machine(true,candies-1,coins)
    }
  }

  def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = {
    import State._
    val list: State[Machine, List[Unit]] = sequence(inputs.map(input => modify(update(input))))
    list.flatMap((_: List[Unit]) =>
       State(
         s => {
           val currentState: State[Machine, Machine] = get   // <= my doubt is here
           val (currentMachine, newState) = currentState.run(s)
           ((currentMachine.coins, currentMachine.candies), newState)
         }
       )
     )
  }
}
```

My doubt is about the following line in `simulateMachine` definition:

```
val getState: State[Machine, Machine] = get
```

`simulateMachine` implements a desugared version I wrote to better understanding the internals of the original for comprehension I actually wrote to solve the exercise.

**My question is:**

why I need to explicitly specify the type of `currentState` to make the code compiling? Indeed, without that `State[Machine, Machine]` type definition the above snippet does not compile.

Why the compiler is not able to infer the actual type? Is that just a matter of type inference limitation or am I missing something here?

Hope my question is clear, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't supply type arguments to `get` and don't specify the type of `currentState` explicitly Scala has no way of knowing the type. It would have to infer the type backwards from `((currentMachine.coins, currentMachine.candies), newState)` and `val (currentMachine, newState) = currentState.run(s)` but Scala's type inference is not powerful enough to do that.

Comment: thank you, instead if I do something like:  `for {
      _ <- list
      s <- get
    } yield(s.coins, s.candies)` the type inference works better?

Comment: @P3trur0 I don't think it's guaranteed to always work without explicit types, but it does stand a better chance because it's a single expression.